# Android Activity class array Issue

Tags: android

```
String[] classes = {"Activity","Activity1"};

for( i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {

       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),classes[i].class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });
}
```

Here is problem with classes[i].class . Is it possible . Need help

Comment: And the "issue" is...?

Comment: classes[i].class it is shows error.   - Cannot refer to a non-final variable classes inside an inner class defined in a different method
 - Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 1):

So many things wrong with this code.

1)To access a variable in an anonymous inner class like that, it must be declared as final.

2)It won't work anyway-  the class of "Activity" isn't Activity.class, it's String.class.  Because "Activity" is a string.  If you want this code to work, you need an array Class, not an array of Strings.  And then the two members would need to be Activity.class and Activity1.class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
You need to made few changes in your code:

First: You can declare your array string of classes, in this way:

```
 String[] classes = {"YourPackageName.Activity","YourPackageName.Activity1"};
```

Second: For starting the activity.

```
 for( i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {

   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(v.getContext(),classes[i]);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    });
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Considering your for loop does not give any kind of Exception, Bcoz i can't test that. But above code should work in order to start your Activity.

Comment: Your welcome Russel Monzur, and you can accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Here I use new final variable in onclick function . But I need increase the value of the variable . If use i there is still error shows and that is  -------  Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method  .